# How to read a stream in a simple way in scala?

Tags: scala

To read from a stream in Java I would do the usual:

```
byte buff[] = new byte[10]
int len = 0;
while ((len = inputStream.read(buff)) != -1){
 ...do something with buff..
}
```

I know scala offers things like [Source.fromInputStream](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/io/Source$.html#fromInputStream(is:java.io.InputStream)(implicitcodec:scala.io.Codec):scala.io.BufferedSource) but I see it a bit heavy to be honest. I know the above won't work in Scala because the assignment doesn't return the value. Is there a simple way without using the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to close over mutable state and use `Iterator.continually` like so:

```
val buff = Array.ofDim[Byte](10)
Iterator.continually(inputStream.read(buff))
  .takeWhile(_ != -1)
  .foreach { len =>
    // do something wit buff and len
  }
```

being a more or less direct translation of Java code. I'd reach for the libraries based on task at hand, however.